# how to send a php's printed form trough ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, submit

I have a navegator where I can search other users profile, the result of these searches are showed by an 'echo' with php... and these results have a form wich I need to send with ajax but no matter what I do I just can't stop the submit event...

the result of search it's something like...

```
        $mensaje .= '
        <form method="POST" action="users/myfile.php" id="compare">
        <input type="text" name="id_user" value="'.$id_user.'"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>';

echo $message;
```

and then I try to use ajax for loading a file without refreshing the page.

```
$('#compare').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
                            $('.profile-content').fadeIn('fast');
                            $('.profile-content').load('users/myfile.php');

        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

using this, the result I got is the page just going to myfile.php instead of show what I need to show

Answer (score 0):

Response from server is contained in `data` variable which is argument of success function. I don't know what you exactly want to do with your data but you can try `alert(data)` to see if the result is good. The thing you are trying with `.load()` function is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The success callback function has data which can be used for your updation operation. see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

> success
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

```
$('#compare').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
             $('.profile-content').fadeIn('fast');
             //updation-starts
             $('.profile-content').html(data.content);
             //updation-ends
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```